# How to make a graph of derivatives for a set of points

Tags: data

Hello and merry christmas! I've been trying to get a simple graph of derivatives (graph slope) out of a set of data.
I read here this is the way to do it, but couldn't manage to make that work. [image: my trial]

Comment: Try: `c = D[b, x]` and `Plot[{b, c}, {x, 8, 32}]`.

Comment: @Syed, Sadly, same exact thing happened. No success.

Comment: Please include code as text, not pictures. I think you might have spurious definitions somewhere, considering the output of your `c = b'`: clear the definition of b and try again. Note also that b is already a function of x in the way you defined it. Perhaps try this: `b = Interpolation[dataPerformance]` then `Plot[b'[x], {x, 8, 32}]` or `ListLinePlot[b', InterpolationOrder -> 3]`.

Comment: I must note that I typed out everything since you have included a screenshot. You can include copy-paste-able code to get more dependable answers. I think you just need to restart Mma and try the code in the answer.

Comment: I'm truly sorry, didn't think of that @Syed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dataPerformance = {{8, 105}, {14, 71}, {16, 66}, {24, 48}, {32, 42}};
```

Define `b` as a **pure function**

```
b = Interpolation[dataPerformance];

Plot[{b[x], b'[x]}, {x, 8, 32},
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[dataPerformance]},
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.8, .27}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To smooth out the derivative, look at the options for [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html)

```
Options[Interpolation]

(* {InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> Automatic, 
    PeriodicInterpolation -> False} *)
```

Then look at the effect of changing the [`InterpolationOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html)

```
Manipulate[
 b = Interpolation[dataPerformance,
   InterpolationOrder -> io];
 Plot[{b[x], b'[x]}, {x, 8, 32},
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
    Point[dataPerformance]},
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.8, .27}]],
 {{io, 3, "InterpolationOrder"},
  Range[0, Length[dataPerformance] - 1]}]
```

[image]